# How to save my current game into cache?

Tags: android, caching, object, surfaceview

I'm currently developing an android game using SurfaceView and i want to save my GameField class/object to the cache.

Can you please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this should explain it:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to save the game state to the device so it can be restored when the application restarts?  If so, consider using `SharedPreferences` as outlined here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

If SharedPreferences won't work, here is an article about all the basic persisted storage options available:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: no, i just want to save my object/class to the cache so that i can continue my current game when i restart the application.

Comment: @DonDavidJr.Julian When you say cache, I think you mean the SharedPreferences.  These stick around after when the application stops and can be retrieved when the app restarts.  A cache usually refers to data that is lost when the application (or cache) stops.

Comment: so where should save my objects and how? tnx

Comment: @DonDavidJr.Julian You have to 'Serialize' your objects to save them.  This means turning them into something that can be saved.  Common formats include XML and Json but there are others as well.  Usually though, instead of serializing and deserializing objects, it's easier to only save a small amount of data to restart the game (eg. level, score, lives, timeleft, current sprite positions, etc.)

Comment: I tried to serialize my object. but my class contains field Rect bounds . and when I try to my class it throws an exception java.io.NotSerializableExeption..

Comment: @DonDavidJr.Julian I wouldn't recommend using the standard Java serialization.  You can save the state of an object just by extracting the primitive values of its fields.